# With Javascript, how can I have a window reload 1 second after a link is clicked that downloads a file?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a list of files that my employee's need to download. I have it when they click the file, it goes, moves the file to a new location so we know they downloaded it, then passes the file to their browser and they download it... so the page they are on does not really change.

I want to make it where when they click that link and it goes and does what it does that it then reloads the current page. So I figured the best way to do it, is to have javascript when they click that link, to one second later reload the current page.

But everything I've tried has failed. the page does not reload. (The list of files is built dynamically, so it only shows the files they did not download yet. I can tell them to just hit F5, but I'd prefer to make it automatically do it for them)

Can you show me how to do it the right way?

Here is what I did (in the script these are the two functions I wrote):

```
    runReload () {
       setTimeout(myTimeFunction, 1000);
    }

    myTimeFunction() {
       document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

and on the link, I put:

```
    onclick=\"runReload();\"
```

But nothing happens.

So, what did I miss?
Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Have you looked at the Javascript console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I just checked, nothing is on the console... so must not be an error, but nothing happens either... I guess I should put an "alert" in there, so I'll know if it is getting executed... brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `function` keyword to tell JavaScript that your code blocks are functions:

```
function runReload () {
   setTimeout(myTimeFunction, 1000);
}

function myTimeFunction() {
   document.location.reload(true);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spxyv897/

Note that I changed your reload method to just use an alert box in order to support the jsfiddle environment

Comment: OMG, DUH, on my part!! geeze. I been writing Perl language so much, I did not even notice that!! Thank you!


That fixed it. It works now. I had to increase it to 2000 because 1000 was not long enough, so it reloaded the page before the file started the download. I may increase it to 2500 to be safe. but thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
function runReload () {
   setTimeout(myTimeFunction, 1000);
}

function myTimeFunction() {
   document.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Fair point, I never considered that, it just seemed like it would cause conflict but I just checked and it doesn't, I'll remove it.

Comment: It's common (though probably a bad practice) to `echo` html in php, or do similar in other languages, while doing so you would have to escape the quotes. Likely where they came from

Comment: Yeah, I remember doing exactly that a few years ago, it slipped my mind though.